# P2P payments inside Android app with Paypal

Tags: android, paypal, p2p, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to accomplish the simple (in theory...) task of letting a user of my Android app make a payment to another user of the app. It seems that Paypal is the only viable way to do this (at least in Europe), so I went to their site and found a link to their [Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md). Cool, however after some reading it turns out that this SDK only allows payments from the user to the app's account, and not from a user to another user.

So I did some research and it seems that there is something called [Mobile Payment Libraries](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) which does the job. Wonderful, however they explicitly say on their site that this is old and will be totally replaced by the new SDK.

Ok, I then continued my research and found out that these libraries are based on the "Adaptive Payments API", which is a set of REST APIs which seem to do exactly what I need. However their documentation seems tailor-made for browser - not mobile - applications. For example, you need to login on a web page to authenticate the payment, and I would prefer to avoid this in favour of a totally in-app user experience.

Bottom line: after some hours spent reading a bunch of cahotic documentation, I'm back to the starting point. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong places, but this should be a very common use-case and had imagined it would take a couple of lines of code with a decent libary.

So I'm asking: is anyone able to provide a working example of an Android Activity allowing the user to pay another user by inserting his Paypal credentials and the recipient's email?

Comment: I'm currently struggling the same as you. Did you find a solution? I'm happy to switch from PayPal to some other service.

Comment: Same here. Any progress?